# Vuejs Embedded JSON

Tags: json, sqlite, vue.js

Tell me how to extract data from the embedded json. The data in Vuejs is transferred from the database. There is data in the debugger in Google Chrome. There is a one-to-many relationship in the database. One recipe for many ingredients

Example Vue

```
  var vm =  new Vue({
        el: '#my_view',
        data: {
            recipeslist: [],
            recipes: {}
        },
        created: function () {
            this.$http.get('/recipe').then(function (data) {         
                this.$set(this, 'recipeslist', data.body.items)
                $( "#recipe_view" ).hide();
            })
        },
        methods: {
            showrecipe: function (event) {
                this.$http.get('/recipe/'+event.target.id).then(function (data) {                   
                    this.$set(this, 'recipes', data.body.items)               
                    $( "#recipe_view" ).show();
                    $( "#main_view" ).hide();


                })                
            }
        }
    })
```

Example html

```
<div class="root"v-for="index in recipes">
  <h6> {{index.recipename}} </h6>
  <h6> {{index.flavorid}} </h6>
</div>
```

Html view

```
test 1

3

test 1

4
```

Example data with this code

```
<div class="root"v-for="index in recipes">
  <h6> {{index}} </h6>
</div>
```

```
{ "id": 1, "bottleID": 1, "recipename": "test 1", "bottlesize": 60, "date": 1, "flavorslist": 1, "note": "none", "flavorid": 3, "NAME": "tpa lime", "drops": 5, "recepeid": 1 }

{ "id": 1, "bottleID": 1, "recipename": "test 1", "bottlesize": 60, "date": 1, "flavorslist": 1, "note": "none", "flavorid": 4, "NAME": "tpa prome", "drops": 1, "recepeid": 1 }
```

Tried so writes an error: *vue.min.js:6 TypeError: Cannot read property 'recipename' of undefined*

```
   <div class="root"v-for="index in recipes">
             <h6> {{index[0].recipename}} </h6>
             <h6> {{index[0].flavorid}} </h6>
  </div>
```

In general, I need to get:

One copy of recipename, bottleID, bottlesize, date (since this is the basis of the recipe and it is the same in json) But a few NAME, drops (since these are ingredients and there may be several)

[SQL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8rOqd.jpg)

[Google Chrome Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GzT5j.jpg)

Comment: I don't understand your problem. How does your json object look like? Is it an array of objects? What do you mean with `embedded` json? Is it a nested object or is it a array-like object? I've created a basic [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/1stu5yam/) for you.

Comment: Yes, json array. In your example, id and recipename are different, but they are the same for me, differ only  NAME, drops.Please see my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rcnow/tmm8m7by/) I showed that I need

Comment: OK, now I think I've understood you use-case. If you group your array by id or recipeName then you can loop through your array as needed. By `id` is better because id is a unique property. Please have a look at this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/tmm8m7by/2/)

Comment: Many thanks. Everything is working. Lodash.js required?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments after grouping the array by id you can iterate through it and render your data with two `v-fors`:

- 1st loop to get the groups
- 2nd loop to render the ingredients

[Lodash](https://lodash.com/) is not required. But it simplifies your code and it's better tested then self coded. Anyway I've added a basic grouping method that is doing the grouping. I would use own grouping method if it is the only part of your app that requires lodash.

Please have a look at the demo below or this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/spqd0b86/).

```js
//
const jsonData = [{
    "id": 1,
    "bottleID": 1,
    "recipename": "test 1",
    "bottlesize": 60,
    "date": 1,
    "flavorslist": 1,
    "note": "none",
    "flavorid": 3,
    "NAME": "tpa lime",
    "drops": 5,
    "recepeid": 1
  },

  {
    "id": 1,
    "bottleID": 1,
    "recipename": "test 1",
    "bottlesize": 60,
    "date": 1,
    "flavorslist": 1,
    "note": "none",
    "flavorid": 4,
    "NAME": "tpa prome",
    "drops": 1,
    "recepeid": 1
  }
]

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    let groupedJson = this.groupBy(jsonData, (obj) => obj.id) // _.groupBy(jsonData, (obj) => obj.id)
    console.log('grouped by id', JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(groupedJson)))
    return {
      json: groupedJson
    }
  },
  methods: {
    groupBy(data, iterator) {
      let result = {}
      for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        let id = iterator(data[i])
        if (!result[id]) result[id] = []
        result[id].push(Object.assign({}, data[i]))
      }
      return result
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.2/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app" v-cloak>
  <p>Original data</p>
  <ul>
    <li v-for="(recipes, id) in json">
      {{json[id][0].recipename}}
      <ul>
        <li v-for="recipe in recipes">
          {{recipe.NAME}} - {{recipe.drops}}
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div>
  <p>It should be</p>
  <ul>
    <li>test 1</li>
    <li> tpa lime - 5</li>
    <li>tpa prome - 1</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```